# Yargs - How to provide custom error msg for omitted positional argument

Tags: node.js, command-line-interface, yargs

I can't find a way to properly configure positional arguments. I have this code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

const create = (argv) => {
  console.log('create component with name:', argv.name)
}

const createBuilder = (yargs) => {
  yargs.positional('name', {
    desc: 'Name of the new component',
  })
}

/* eslint-disable no-unused-expressions */
require('yargs')
  .command({
    command: 'create <name>',
    desc: 'Create a new component',
    builder: createBuilder,
    handler: create,
  })
  .demandCommand(1, 'A command is required')
  .help()
  .argv
```

and I would like to provide a custom error message in case the user doesn't specify a name after the create command.

It's not clear to me from the documentation how to do that, and while going through github issues I came across this comment (#928):

> I recommend instead using demandCommand and demandOption (each of
>   which are documented).
>
> These allow you to configure positional arguments and flag arguments
>   separately

I've tried all kinds of combinations with

```
.demandCommand(1, 'You need to provide name for the new component')
```

or

```
.demandOption('name', 'You need to provide name for the new component')
```

but without luck. Does anybody know how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

tl;dr - try making your command a default command by adding the string `*` or `$0` to the start of your command name.

I've found that the positional arguments are only respected (ie: show up in the help menu and throw an error when a required positional isn't provided) when the positional argument is defined in a [default command](https://github.com/yargs/yargs/blob/master/docs/advanced.md#default-commands).

Here's an example of getting it to work with your code (note that you no longer have to use `.demandCommand()`):

```js
require('yargs')
  .scriptName('cli-app')
  .command({
    command: '$0 create <name>',
    desc: 'Create a new component',
    builder: yargs => {
      yargs.positional('name', {
        desc: 'Name of the new component'
      });
    },
    handler: function(argv) {
      console.log('this is the handler function!');
    }
  })
  .help().argv;
```

Output (note the "Not enough non-option arguments: got 1, need at least 2" line at the end):

```sh
➞ node cli-app.js create                                                                                                                                       1 ↵
cli-app create <name>

Create a new component

Positionals:
  name  Name of the new component

Options:
  --version  Show version number                                       [boolean]
  --help     Show help                                                 [boolean]

Not enough non-option arguments: got 1, need at least 2
```

Answer (score 0):

The command option of [yargs](https://github.com/yargs/yargs) can take two types of arguments.

The first being **Obligatory**: `<varName>`. If for some reason, the user type the command without entering a `varName`, then it will run the help page.

The second being **Optional**: `[varName]`. If the user enters the command, even with a missing `varName`, the command will run.

Extra: if you want infinite `varName` variables, then you can provide a [spread operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/scripting/javascript/reference/spread-operator-decrement-dot-dot-dot-javascript) for the **wanted** option. Being `<...varNames>` or `[...varNames]`

---

That being said, if you want to provide a custom error message, there are several ways of going about it. The first is this one:

```
const program = require('yargs')
    .command('create [fileName]', 'your description', () => {}, argv => {
        if(argv.fileName === undefined) {
            console.error('You need to provide name for the new component')
            return;
        }
        console.log(`success, a component called ${argv.fileName} got created.`)
    })
```

Lodash also provides a [function _.isUndefined](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#isUndefined) which would also work.

---

The second is this one:

```
const program = require('yargs')
    .command('create <fileName>', 'A description', () => {}, argv => {

    }).fail((msg, err, yargs) => {
        console.log('Sorry, no component name was given.')
    })

program.argv
```

For more information, here is the [fail documentation](https://github.com/yargs/yargs/blob/HEAD/docs/api.md#fail) on yargs api.

Comment: thank you, but I feel this is more of workaround, than a solution using the yargs api. A problem I see is that -h would display: `create [fileName]  Create a new component` marking fileName as optional, whereas I want to communicate it is required.

Comment: The second example *fixed* your issue?

Comment: Not really, it will still call the handler with `undefined`, so I'll have to handle that. Also I don't know what other errors might cause `fail` to be called, so i'll have to add code to figure that out. Plus the user feedback by means of console.log/error is not consistent with the messages returned by `demandCommand` and `demandOption`. I was hoping for something like `demandPositional` ... I may just open issue on github. I appreciate your help though!